# Default Image sizes in ttk.Label

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Currently I'm using this snippet of code which seems pretty easy:

```
label = ttk.Label(mainframe)
image1 = PhotoImage(file='my_image.gif')
label['image'] = image1
label.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

However, if I edit the size of my_image.gif in photoshop, then run it again, the image gets stretched to the same size, and this seems to continue no matter how small I make the base image. This seems to suggest to me that the PhotoImage or something above it enforces a default size or specific minimum size. I cannot find any documentation to suggest that this is the case.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598360/how-can-i-display-an-image-in-python-3-using-tkinter-ttk) I found the help(PhotoImage) suggestion which I used. When in the python interpreter I run the help(PhotoImage) command and I found this:

```
height(self)
    Return the height of the image.
type(self)
    Return the type of the imgage, e.g. "photo" or "bitmap".
width(self)
    Return the width of the image.
```

But it doesn't seem to provide me with an image sizing of any type either.

After searching all over and seeing no reference at all, i'm beginning to suspect that using images in a Label is for a specific purpose and I'm approaching this all wrong. All i'm trying to do is place a logo at the top of the window, but I want the logo to be limited in size so it doesn't take over the whole window.

Also of note is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624309/is-there-an-in-depth-ttk-styling-guide-available) which seems to be lacking an answer but I too am curious if there is some documentation on it. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I did check the python documentation and the http://www.tkdocs.com site for more information.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using variously scaled gif images on python 2.7.  It worked fine - the variously scaled images displayed correctly, with no stretching.  Maybe it has something to do with your geometry manager?  Can you post more context for your code (or is what you posted all that you have?)

Comment: @Brionius - I appreciate your feedback. I stepped away and took a break, came back and it's working now. I'm trying to reproduce it again myself but can only conclude that I was making some very ridiculous error. This is only my second post on overstock though, and I think I learned a valuable lesson about taking a break before posting and/or not posting when frustrated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I made an error, but I have no clue what it was. In the end this was this code that did it for me:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("ImageTest")
label = ttk.Label(root)
image1 = PhotoImage(file='my_image.gif')
label['image'] = image1
label.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It's all working now as expected.