# Placing an image using ttk on a grid, with Python 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, grid, ttk

I am stuck when I try to place an image on my GUI. Based on the program I am working on, I am restricted to working with Python v2.7.11.  I have a basic GUI that I pulled from elsewhere (shown below, top code).  However, when I try to place an image using a similar process, my GUI goes away altogether (no other features show). Edit: The error I am receiving is "image "pyimage28" doesn't exist, even though I'm defining my image as 'bug.gif'. The full error message is shown in the second code snippet; both the code and the image are located in on the Desktop.

Based on another question on this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175328/default-image-sizes-in-ttk-label), my attempt is shown below, starting with the variable "label".

Ultimately, I would like to do two things.

1. Place an image in the upper left corner of the GUI in place of where the `frame` item was
2. Give that image properties, such that I can store x,y coordinates when I click somewhere on the image, or the coordinates show in real time outside of the image.

.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

content = ttk.Frame(root)
#frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100)

label = ttk.Label(root)
image1 = PhotoImage(file='bug.gif')
label['image'] = image1

latlbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Latitude")
latval = ttk.Entry(content)
lonlbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Longitude")
lonval = ttk.Entry(content)

onevar = BooleanVar()
twovar = BooleanVar()
threevar = BooleanVar()
onevar.set(True)
twovar.set(False)
threevar.set(True)

one = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="One", variable=onevar, onvalue=True)
two = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Two", variable=twovar, onvalue=True)
three = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Three", variable=threevar, onvalue=True)
ok = ttk.Button(content, text="Okay")
cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Cancel")

content.grid(column=0, row=0)

#frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)

label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)
latlbl.grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=1)
latval.grid(column=4, row=0, columnspan=2)
lonlbl.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=1)
lonval.grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=2)
one.grid(column=0, row=3)
two.grid(column=1, row=3)
three.grid(column=2, row=3)
ok.grid(column=3, row=3)
cancel.grid(column=4, row=3)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The full code error is:

```
runfile('C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop/untitled9.py', wdir='C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-1596c9c787bc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop/untitled9.py', wdir='C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop/untitled9.py", line 25, in <module>
label['image'] = image1

  File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1333, in __setitem__
self.configure({key: value})

  File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1326, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1317, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: The image, bug-gif, is possibly in a directory that Python does not search.  Please post the entire error message.

Comment: Per your suggestion, the full error code was added.

Comment: Copy the "photo=" image from this page, place it on the label using "data=", and see if it works http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm  If it does, then the problem is that Python can not locate the image.

Comment: I copied the "photo=" line from that page, and used:

    photo = PhotoImage(data=photo)
    image1 = PhotoImage(file=photo)
    label['image'] = image1

To fix the situation where the program cannot find the image, I've also tried putting in the full file path ("C:/Users/ajpung/Desktop/bug.gif"). Same result.

Comment: Sometimes is problem with PhotoImage and Garbage Collection (but rather inside function) http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm . Maybe you have this problem.

Comment: This code does not give the error that you say it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley -- I just copied my code, restarted my kernel, and got the same error.  Keep in mind, I'm using Python 2.7.11 -- not sure if that matters.

Comment: I ran the code with python 2.7.6 and it works fine (when you fix the error I described in my answer). No error is thrown. There is nothing in your code that can cause the error you say it does. You simply must be running different code.

Comment: I tried to reduce my code, removing all the buttons, etc.  In a new Spyder window, I've copied and run same code.  Based on your subsequent comment, I'll look into the Spyder issue -- thank you for your patience!

Comment: It would help if you mentioned that you're using Spyder rather than a more common python interpreter. That might have something to do with it Though, if it does, it seems like it would be a bug in Spyder because the code looks fine except for the one issue with packing the label.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not give the error you say it does when running in a standard python interpreter.

That being said, there is one critical bug in your code that will prevent it from working. You are using both `grid` and `pack` in the root window. You need to remove this line:

```
label.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd tried this before, but the problem isn't with Spyder.  Switching `root = Tk()` to `root = Toplevel()` fixed the original issue.